# Hash trait does not work for Rc<RefCell<T>> in enum

Tags: rust, hash, enums, traits, refcell

I define a struct `MyData` and implement `PartialEq` and `Hash` traits for it manually.

I define a enum which includes `Rc<MyData>` and `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>`.

I want derive `PartialEq` and `Hash` for the enum, but fails:

1. The `PartialEq` and `Hash` both work for `Rc<MyData>`;
2. The `PartialEq` works for `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>` too;
3. But the `Hash` does not work for `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>` !

I have 2 questions:

1. Why? Why only the `Hash` does not work only for `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>`?
2. How to fix it?

   I can not implement `Hash` for `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>`.  After searching around I find a way: defining a new wrapper struct, like `struct RRWrapper<T> (Rc<RefCell<T>>)`, and then implement `Hash` for this `RRWrapper`. But this will bring much code. Is there an idiomatic way? I think this's a general usage.

Thank in advance,

Wu

PS: In the real code of my program, there is only `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>` in the enum but no `Rc<MyData>`. I put `Rc<MyData>` here just for comparision.
PS2: In the real code of my program, there are more than one `Rc<RefCell<T>>` in the enum.

---

Original source code:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

struct MyData {
    i: i64,
}

impl Hash for MyData {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.hash(state);
    }
}
impl PartialEq for MyData {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self == other
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Hash)]
enum MyEnum {
    INT(i64),
    STR(String),
    MYDATA1(Rc<MyData>), // OK both
    MYDATA2(Rc<RefCell<MyData>>), // OK for PartialEq but not for Hash
}

fn main() {
}
```

Error:

```
20  | #[derive(PartialEq, Hash)]
    |                     ---- in this derive macro expansion
...
25  |     MYDATA2(Rc<RefCell<MyData>>), // OK for PartialEq but not for Hash
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Hash` is not implemented for `RefCell<MyData>`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Hash` for `Rc<RefCell<MyData>>`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Hash` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Source code of `struct RRWrapper`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct RRWrapper<T: Hash+PartialEq+Eq>(Rc<RefCell<T>>);

impl<T: Hash+PartialEq+Eq> Deref for RRWrapper<T> {
    type Target = Rc<RefCell<T>>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
impl<T: Hash+PartialEq+Eq> Hash for RRWrapper<T> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.0.borrow().hash(state);
    }
}
impl<T: Hash+PartialEq+Eq> Clone for RRWrapper<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        RRWrapper(self.0.clone())
    }
}
impl<T: Hash+PartialEq+Eq> RRWrapper<T> {
    pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
        RRWrapper(Rc::new(RefCell::new(inner)))
    }
}
```

Comment: You are struggling to *derive* `Hash` for your enum, but you should have no trouble implementing it manually. But as @Netwave said, it's not necessarily a good idea to make an object with interior mutability hashable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why? Why only the Hash does not work only for Rc<RefCell>?

If you think about it it makes sense that `Hash` is not implemented for `RefCell`. Since it is an abstraction for interior mutability, what could be the hash of something that may change? In general, mutable things are not suitable to work as `Hash` objects because of that.

> How to fix it?

Exactly as you did. Taking responsibility in what you exactly want. Implementing it for a wrapper.

Comment: `String` is also mutable and it has `Hash`. Similarly, I think it makes sense for `Rc<RefCell<String>>` to have `Hash`.

Comment: I got your point: `RefCell` does not implement `Hash`. Thanks.

Comment: No `let s: String` is not mutable, `let mut s: String` is. However `let r: RefCell<…>` is mutable even though it doesn't use `let mut`.